# How i can show pushed objects in html with js

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I need to push the new object in the array and show it in tables without refreshing the page, I use the `filter` method too for filtering objects in tables, it's my first time making a basic project in javascript. I tried to push some objects but can't show the table added object, thanks for your attention.

here html code:

```js
var products = [{
    ID: 1,
    productName: "HL Road Frame - Back, 58",
    productNumber: "FR-R92B-58",
    color: "Black",
    listPrice: 900.00,
    modifiedDate: "11 Novermber 2021"
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    productName: "HL Mountain Frame - Silver, 41",
    productNumber: "FR-M945-42",
    color: "Silver",
    listPrice: 1364.50,
    modifiedDate: "16 August 2022"
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    productName: "HL Road Frame - Back, 58",
    productNumber: "FR-R92B-58",
    color: "Black",
    listPrice: 700.00,
    modifiedDate: "11 Novermber 2021"
  },
  {
    ID: 4,
    productName: "HL Road Frame - Back, 58",
    productNumber: "FR-R92B-58",
    color: "Black",
    listPrice: 600.00,
    modifiedDate: "11 Novermber 2021"
  },
];



function showProducts() {


  for (let product of products) {
    let tableRow = $("<tr></tr>").addClass("productData");

    let td = $("<td></td>").text(product.productName);
    tableRow.append(td);

    td = $("<td></td>").text(product.productNumber);
    tableRow.append(td);

    td = $("<td></td>").text(product.color);
    tableRow.append(td);

    td = $("<td></td>").text(product.listPrice);
    tableRow.append(td);

    td = $("<td></td>").text(product.modifiedDate);
    tableRow.append(td);


    product.tableRow = tableRow;
    $("#product").append(tableRow);

  }


}

showProducts();

/*product filter*/
function filterProduct() {
  let pName = $("#pName").val().toLowerCase();
  let minPrice = $("#minPrice").val();
  let maxPrice = $("#maxPrice").val();

  for (let product of products) {

    let toDisplay = (pName.trim() == "" || product.productName.toLowerCase().indexOf(pName) >= 0) &&
      product.listPrice >= minPrice &&
      maxPrice >= product.listPrice;

    let tableRow = product.tableRow;

    if (toDisplay) {
      tableRow.removeClass("fadeOut");
      tableRow.fadeIn();
    } else {
      tableRow.addClass("fadeOut");
      tableRow.fadeOut();
    }
  }
}

$("#filterDiv input").on("change", filterProduct);

/*show-hide*/
let showFilter = document.getElementById("showFilter");

$(showFilter).click(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show Filter' ? 'Hide Filter' : 'Show Filter');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="headtext">
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <button id="showFilter" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filterDiv">Show Filter</button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse" id="filterDiv">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pName" />
      <label>Price between</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="minPrice" placeholder="0" />
      <label>and</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="maxPrice" placeholder="10000" value="10000" />
      <button id="clearButton" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <table id="product" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Product Number</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>List Price</th>
      <th>Modified Date</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">
    Create New Product
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Add Product</h5>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="productName">Name</label>
              <input id="productName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="productNumber">Product Number</label>
              <input id="productNumber" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ender Product Number" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="productColor">Color</label>
              <input id="productColor" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ender Product color">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="listPrice">List Price</label>
              <input id="listPrice" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Ender Price" min="0" max="10000">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="startDate">Sell Start Date</label>
              <input id="startDate" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" placeholder="Ender Product color">
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit">Add Product</button>

          </form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the click event of `#btnSubmit` then do a [preventDefault](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp#:%7E:text=The%20preventDefault()%20method%20cancels,link%20from%20following%20the%20URL) to stop the form from submitting. Then you can create a new product object from the form values and with that object create a row. [Push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) the new product to your `products` array and append the row to the table.

```js
var products = [{
    ID: 1,
    productName: "HL Road Frame - Back, 58",
    productNumber: "FR-R92B-58",
    color: "Black",
    listPrice: 900.00,
    modifiedDate: "11 Novermber 2021"
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    productName: "HL Mountain Frame - Silver, 41",
    productNumber: "FR-M945-42",
    color: "Silver",
    listPrice: 1364.50,
    modifiedDate: "16 August 2022"
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    productName: "HL Road Frame - Back, 58",
    productNumber: "FR-R92B-58",
    color: "Black",
    listPrice: 700.00,
    modifiedDate: "11 Novermber 2021"
  },
  {
    ID: 4,
    productName: "HL Road Frame - Back, 58",
    productNumber: "FR-R92B-58",
    color: "Black",
    listPrice: 600.00,
    modifiedDate: "11 Novermber 2021"
  },
];



function showProducts() {


  for (let product of products) {
    let tableRow = $("<tr></tr>").addClass("productData");

    let td = $("<td></td>").text(product.productName);
    tableRow.append(td);

    td = $("<td></td>").text(product.productNumber);
    tableRow.append(td);

    td = $("<td></td>").text(product.color);
    tableRow.append(td);

    td = $("<td></td>").text(product.listPrice);
    tableRow.append(td);

    td = $("<td></td>").text(product.modifiedDate);
    tableRow.append(td);


    product.tableRow = tableRow;
    $("#product").append(tableRow);

  }


}

showProducts();

/*product filter*/
function filterProduct() {
  let pName = $("#pName").val().toLowerCase();
  let minPrice = $("#minPrice").val();
  let maxPrice = $("#maxPrice").val();

  for (let product of products) {

    let toDisplay = (pName.trim() == "" || product.productName.toLowerCase().indexOf(pName) >= 0) &&
      product.listPrice >= minPrice &&
      maxPrice >= product.listPrice;

    let tableRow = product.tableRow;

    if (toDisplay) {
      tableRow.removeClass("fadeOut");
      tableRow.fadeIn();
    } else {
      tableRow.addClass("fadeOut");
      tableRow.fadeOut();
    }
  }
}

$("#filterDiv input").on("change", filterProduct);

/*show-hide*/
let showFilter = document.getElementById("showFilter");

$(showFilter).click(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show Filter' ? 'Hide Filter' : 'Show Filter');
});

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevents it from doing default submit action

  const product = {
    productName: $("#productName").val(),
    productNumber: $("#productNumber").val(),
    color: $("#productColor").val(),
    listPrice: $("#listPrice").val(),
    modifiedDate: $("#startDate").val(), //create function to format date
  }

  let tableRow = $("<tr></tr>").addClass("productData");

  let td = $("<td></td>").text(product.productName);
  tableRow.append(td);

  td = $("<td></td>").text(product.productNumber);
  tableRow.append(td);

  td = $("<td></td>").text(product.color);
  tableRow.append(td);

  td = $("<td></td>").text(product.listPrice);
  tableRow.append(td);

  td = $("<td></td>").text(product.modifiedDate);
  tableRow.append(td);

  product.tableRow = tableRow;

  products.push(product);
  $("#product").append(tableRow);

  $(this).closest("form").trigger("reset"); //clears the form
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="headtext">
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <button id="showFilter" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filterDiv">Show Filter</button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse" id="filterDiv">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pName" />
      <label>Price between</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="minPrice" placeholder="0" />
      <label>and</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="maxPrice" placeholder="10000" value="10000" />
      <button id="clearButton" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <table id="product" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Product Number</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>List Price</th>
      <th>Modified Date</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">
    Create New Product
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Add Product</h5>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="productName">Name</label>
              <input id="productName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="productNumber">Product Number</label>
              <input id="productNumber" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ender Product Number" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="productColor">Color</label>
              <input id="productColor" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ender Product color">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="listPrice">List Price</label>
              <input id="listPrice" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Ender Price" min="0" max="10000">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="startDate">Sell Start Date</label>
              <input id="startDate" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" placeholder="Ender Product color">
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit">Add Product</button>

          </form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```